# Saving Number of Lines in File as a Variable in Batch File

Tags: variables, batch-file

I have this really nice line in my batch file that tells me how many lines are in a file:

```
 find /v /c "" C:\Users\c1921\mypath\myfolder\!$Unit!.txt
```

This is nice and gives me 31 for the particular file I'm working with. My problem is the file looks something like this:

```
 Microsoft (R) Windows Script Host Version 5.8
 Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.

 my_handled
 219278
 check
 219276
 control
 219274
```

I want to be able to skip the first three lines entirely and then save the first value and then use the second value in my next command etc.

How do I save the number (e.g. 31) into a variable in my batch file?

On a hunch I tried setting a variable like so but it wasn't effective:

```
set "$testVar="""
echo !$testVar!
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This command allows you to "save the number (e.g. 31) into a variable in my batch file":

```
for /F %%a in ('find /v /c "" ^< C:\Users\c1921\mypath\myfolder\!$Unit!.txt') do set numLines=%%a
```

This command allows you "to skip the first three lines entirely" and process the rest:

```
for /F "skip=3 delims=" %%a in (C:\Users\c1921\mypath\myfolder\!$Unit!.txt) do echo Processing: "%%a"
```

However, in my opinion this problem could be entirely avoided if the three first lines in the text file are supressed from the very beginning. I think this file is generated via a VBScript of JScript program that is executed this way:

```
cscript progname.vbs > C:\Users\c1921\mypath\myfolder\!$Unit!.txt
```

The first three lines in the text file may be avoided adding `//nologo` switch this way:

```
cscript //nologo progname.vbs > C:\Users\c1921\mypath\myfolder\!$Unit!.txt
```

Comment: I've never heard of `//nologo` before that solved that problem. I was going to count the lines and then just skip the first three and then starting on the fourth line, but this works so much better thank you.

Answer (score 1):

```dos
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL
SET /a count=3
SET "first="
FOR /f "skip=3delims=" %%a IN (q25089468.txt) DO (
 IF DEFINED first (CALL :show %%a) ELSE (SET "first=%%a")
)

ECHO count=%count%

GOTO :EOF

:show
ECHO first=%first% second=%1
SET /a count+=2
SET "first="
GOTO :eof
```

I used a file named `q25089468.txt` containing your data for my testing.

You appear to be asking two entirely different things - how to count the lines and how to skip the first 3, then deliver each succeeding pair to another process.